# Django REST Framework - cookies not being set via Response.set_cookie() call...?

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-rest-framework, session-cookies

I have the following standard Response setup in my DRF application:

```
response = Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

I'm then attempting to add a split JWT `header.payload` and `signature` to the response headers with a `response.set_cookie()` call, as follows:

```
        max_age = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60

        expires = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=max_age)

        response.set_cookie(
            key='JWT_ACCESS_HEADER_PAYLOAD',
            value=header_payload,
            httponly=False,
            expires=expires.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC"),
            max_age=max_age
        )

        response.set_cookie(
            key='JWT_ACCESS_SIGNATURE',
            value=signature,
            httponly=True,
            expires=expires.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S UTC"),
            max_age=max_age
        )

        return response
```

I can't see anything wrong with what I have done thus far:

[image: Client Side Response Headers]

Yet, for some reason, the only cookies set on the client side are as follows:

[image: Client Side Storage]

What have I done wrong here??

The actual output in the headers seem to be a valid SetCookie value:

`JWT_ACCESS_HEADER_PAYLOAD=aSasas; expires=Sat, 03-Apr-2021 10:24:31 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; Path=/`

`JWT_ACCESS_SIGNATURE=asaSasaS; expires=Sat, 03-Apr-2021 10:24:31 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=31536000; Path=`

N.B. Running on localhost...if that helps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this seems like a very trivial solution because it is just that.

I was using `axios` ... without sending `{ withCredentials: true }`, with the requests.

The cookies were being set - because, well, they were. It's just to see them I needed to refresh the browser.